# How to download this webpage?

Tags: download

I would like to download this webpage http://www.newsmth.net/nForum/#!article/EconForum/396054 . In Firefox, by Ctrl+S, I can choose "Web page, Complete", "Web page, html only", "Text file" or "All files". But the downloaded webpage cannot be shown correctly under Firefox.

I wonder why and how to download the webpage correctly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions on Web Applications Stack Exchange are expected to relate to web applications within [the scope defined by the community](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 4):

Most likely the content is built dynamically using client-side JavaScript. As such, saving the page won't help you, because the initial HTML to build the page doesn't have that information. A fact of life in this post Web 2.0 world.

You *might* be able to print the page. If so, you can print it to a PDF using one of the many "print to PDF" utilities out there. Then, at least, you'd have a soft-copy of the page.

Comment: Thanks! What does "post Web 2.0 world" mean in "a fact of life in this post Web 2.0 world"?

Comment: In Firefox, why can "print to pdf" capture the content of the webpage, while saving as webpage  cannot?

Comment: Because printing the web page mostly takes what you see and prints it. Saving the web page only saves the HTML of the page, which does not necessarily contain all of the content you see. In today's web, a lot of content is dynamically created rather than embedded in the HTML code.

Comment: Thanks! If I understand correctly, both the server and the client can dynamically create webpages, and those dynamically created on the client side cannot be saved in Firefox (not printing). I wonder if those dynamically created on the server side can be saved in Firefox (not printing)>